# How do I dub just the dialogue for an existing movie?

Tags: video-editor

I am not a moviemaker or have any experience at all in the department. But I saw [this video of BTS dubbing some scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oliy9QPKqPk) from Lionking, Zootopia etc. I want to do the same.

I tried movavi, which allows me to record my own voice but it replaces all the audio for that segment. But I only want to replace/dub over the dialogue while leaving other sound effects intact. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a version of the audio track without any dialogue on it.
You could attempt to remove the dialogue from the a sound track, but the results would be pretty bad.